# Get Value From Textbox to File_get_contents

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputsm">Put URL</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Count Contact">
</div>
```

This code is my text box and button

```
<?php
$getText = file_get_contents("", true);
$Contact = substr_count($getText ,"CONTACTID");
print_r($Contact);
?>
```

and this code is php for  get a value and count

**Example**

I need to put this link https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudpoc2/us-east-1%3A4502ecdd-1994-40da-8eb2-b6ccc96d6be0/Contacts/Contact_2014_11_19_09_53_28_278.vcf  in text box 
and click button it show  number of contact in this file

```
 $getText = file_get_contents("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudpoc2/us-east-1%3A4502ecdd-1994-40da-8eb2-b6ccc96d6be0/Contacts/Contact_2014_11_19_09_53_28_278.vcf", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to submit your form through POST or GET.  My example will use POST.  You also must assign a name to the elements you're posting (such as URL).  This is untested, so it may have some errors. But it will give you an idea.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $getText = file_get_contents("$url", true);
    $Contact = substr_count($getText ,"CONTACTID");
    print_r($Contact);
}
?>  
<form method="POST" action="?">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputsm">Put URL</label>
        <input name="url" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text">
        <br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Count Contact">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry I can't understand can you explain me deeply ?

Comment: $Contact = substr_count($getText ,"CONTACTID");
print_r($Contact);

like this   i count ContacID in that file

Comment: actually i need to get a URL in text box   and place  in  to 

a file_get_contents   you get it ?

Comment: Ah sorry.  I misunderstood where the problem was. You'll need to submit your form, probably with a POST request and then do you file get contents command.  Hold on.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sir I don't have a problem with a output  

I have a problem about  How to get a  URL  as in textbox  

to the file_get_content("");